# Errors with Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I can logon to the Azure Portal using my MSN account. From the portal, I can see the several storage accounts I have created. But I want to do this from PowerShell. So I use the Azure module and issue this command:

Get-AzureStorageAccount

I get the error:
**Psh[Cookham8:Cert:\CurrentUser\my]> get-azurestorageaccount
get-azurestorageaccount : Account with name 'XXXXX_XXX@XXX.com' does not exist.
Parameter name: accountName**

Two things: first the account that Get-AzureStorageAccount is reporting as non existent works perfectly when I login to the portal.

Second: what accountName parameter - that parameter does not exist in the cmdlet?

How do I get Azure to see accounts that exist?

Comment: This appears to have been a glitch in Azure. I came back to the same machine and this now works fine. It must have been a glitch in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the error noted above for several hours. After posting here, I left it, and went home. Came back the next day and it works. I have *other* Azure cmdlet issues, but this one is resolved!

The suggestions around accounts is good (although I had dealt with that already).

Comment: So what was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `add-azureaccount`? When you do that, you will be prompted to login using your Azure account credentials. You should also...

Set subscription name. It can be found in the Storage account dashboard in the portal

```
$SubscriptionName="YourSubscriptionName"
```

Set Storage account name

```
$StorageAccountName="yourstorageaccountname"
```

Set Location

```
$Location = "West US"
```

Set default Azure subscription

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName –Default
```

Set a default storage account.

```
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
```

After doing this, `get-azurestorageaccount` should work. This article might also be helpful http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-powershell-guide-full/

Comment: Yes - I have done both. That is not the issue, although thanks for the time to post your response. Much appreciated. It would appear to be a glitch in Azure.